# Incorrect size of an image in Java?

Tags: java, image, size

I am sorry for my English, English is not my native language.
My problem is incorrect size of an image.
For example, I have the standart image of win "Penguins.jpg" that has size of 760kB.
But Java read about 2.6 mB.
My code:

```
public class Main {

public static void HEX (byte b) {
    switch (b) {
    case 0x00: System.out.print("0"); break;
    case 0x01: System.out.print("1"); break;
    case 0x02: System.out.print("2"); break;
    case 0x03: System.out.print("3"); break;
    case 0x04: System.out.print("4"); break;
    case 0x05: System.out.print("5"); break;
    case 0x06: System.out.print("6"); break;
    case 0x07: System.out.print("7"); break;
    case 0x08: System.out.print("8"); break;
    case 0x09: System.out.print("9"); break;
    case 0x0A: System.out.print("A"); break;
    case 0x0B: System.out.print("B"); break;
    case 0x0C: System.out.print("C"); break;
    case 0x0D: System.out.print("D"); break;
    case 0x0E: System.out.print("E"); break;
    case 0x0F: System.out.print("F"); break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File ("C:\\Java\\Penguins.jpg");
    File MyFile = new File ("C:\\Java\\MyPic.jpg");

    OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (MyFile));

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

    byte [] arr = data.getData();
    System.out.println(arr.length);

    outputStream.write(arr);
}
```

}

Comment: what is the purpose of this code

Comment: I would like to transfer the image to the microcontroller STM32F407 for display on the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way of checking file Size and not getting the array of bytes only.

```
File file = new File ("C:\\Java\\Penguins.jpg");
double bytes = file.length();
double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
```